# Python Pyramid - How to store data, convert to string in session and retrieve it on the next page?

Tags: python, pyramid

I was required to store the data in session and retrieve it later on. My task is to select gifts and show the selected gift for confirmation on next page.

I followed the website [here](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/sessions.html), but I don't understand what does this mean:

```
session['fred'] = 'yes'
```

Thank you, I'm a beginner in Python programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions must be a dictionary where you store values as (key,value) pairs. So, in this case:

```
session['fred'] = 'yes'
```

'Fred' is the key and 'Yes' is the value.

Learn more about python dictionaries, here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

```
 session["abc"] = 123
 print (session["abc"]) this will get you 123
```

Comment: so the value will be the id of the gift selected?

Comment: Correct. It will be value the of the selected gift id.

Comment: but how to retrieve it on next page?

Comment: Not sure what next page means here?

Comment: after storing data in session, I have to get the data and show it on a confirmation page.

Comment: Okay. As you are storing the varialbes in the session. You retrieve them back from the session. Please refer edited answer.

Comment: If you query is solved. Please accept the answer. Thanks and happy learning :)